# How to select the cases which were in the same day within 2 datetime type variables

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a quick question about the mysql query.

Let's suppose I have two columns which are both datetime type vairables, one is start_at, another one is end_at.

And I want to choose all of the cases which start and end in the same day. How can I do that?

I am thinking the queries like this:

```
where year(start_at) = year(end_at)
and month(start_at) = month(end_at)
and day(start_at) = day(end_at);
```

And I am trying to find a better way to approach that goal. Any clue guys?

Answer (score 0):

Much more simply:

```
where date(start_at) = date(end_at)
```